# What is the best way to time django query in shell?

Tags: python, django

I have sometimes to optimize my django queries and want to compare the speed of different queries in django shell. Of course, I can use django-debug-toolbar or smth similar, but I prefer to do it in shell.

For now, I use %timeit in django shell_plus. But maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Yes there is, you should google for profiles and other profile libraries specific to django, look at django-awesome github repo.

Comment: @vishes_shell Thanks, I've tried to, but haven't found smth that I need